# Groub by in an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an response object as below :

```
{
  "orderReturns": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "quantity": 1,
      "createdAt": "2023-03-20T19:07:35.244Z",
      "product": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lite Milk Fat Spread",
        "barcode": "8901262010498",
        "productMrp": "10.00"
      },
      "return": {
        "id": 9,
        "order": {
          "id": 93
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "quantity": 1,
      "createdAt": "2023-03-20T19:07:35.642Z",
      "product": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Honeydew Smooth",
        "barcode": "8901725016012",
        "productMrp": "330.00"
      },
      "return": {
        "id": 9,
        "order": {
          "id": 94
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "quantity": 1,
      "createdAt": "2023-03-20T19:07:36.650Z",
      "product": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Honeydew Smooth",
        "barcode": "8901725016012",
        "productMrp": "330.00"
      },
      "return": {
        "id": 10,
        "order": {
          "id": 94
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "quantity": 1,
      "createdAt": "2023-03-20T19:07:37.069Z",
      "product": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Honeydew Smooth",
        "barcode": "8901725016012",
        "productMrp": "330.00"
      },
      "return": {
        "id": 10,
        "order": {
          "id": 93
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "count": 4
}
```

and I need to return it in a `GROUP BY` clause where I group by `returnId`, where all the orderReturns are grouped by their respective returnIds. For example for returnId = 9, I need id = 10 and 9 to be grouped by returnId = 9 and id = 11 and 12, grouped by returnId = 10. I tried various things but groupBy is giving me an error - "must appear in the group by clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Any tips?

Comment: can you provide example of something you already tried?

Comment: You don't show the SQL you are trying to change -- how do you expect us to tell you what to change if you don't show the SQL.  This is XML, it is the output of the service.  We need the SQL that is used to query the data